# Finding the number of common characters in all input strings - C++14

Tags: c++, string, indexing, stl, character

I was trying to implement a code for a contest which finds the number of common characters in all the input strings.

I've skipped the input format but time constraint was 0.5 sec and so I tried to write the optimum code.
The approach I followed was, while inputting, I mark the string with minimum length to traverse later. Then I loop through that string to extract each character and check if it is in all strings. Once I check for a character, I remove it from all strings to save time.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
string s[205];
int t,len=0,n,k,count1,count2;
char a;
int main()
{
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>n;
        len=0;
        count1=0;
        count2=0;
        k=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
        {
            cin>>s[i];
            if(i==0)
            {
                len = s[i].length();
            }
            else
            {
                if(s[i].length()<len)
                {
                    len = s[i].length(); //Finding string with min length
                    k = i;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<s[k].length();++i)
        {
            count1 = 0;
            a = s[k][i];
            for(int j=0;j<n;++j)
            {
                auto found = s[j].find(a);
                if(found==std::string::npos) //checking each character in all strings
                    break;
                else
                    count1++;
            }
            if(count1==n) //If char is in all strings
            {
                count2++;
            }
            for(int j=0;j<n;++j)
            {
                if(s[j].find(a)!=std::string::npos)
                {
                    s[j].erase(std::remove(s[j].begin(), s[j].end(), a), s[j].end()); //removing checked character from all strings
                }
            }

        }
        cout<<count2<<"\n"; //number of common characters

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code ran for couple  of test cases but failed for most of them. Please let me know if there is a logical flaw in the code.

Comment: The requirements of the task are somewhat unclear: are there duplicate characters in the strings, for example? Also, since you're tagging with c++ and have c++14 in the title, are you allowed to use std::set? And lastly, removing characters from the strings seems like a lot more work than it's worth.

Comment: Do you have input data for failed test cases and did you try to debug it with a debugger?

Comment: @Pzc, Yes, there are duplicates in the string and no, there are no constraints on the libraries that can be used.

Comment: @ThomasSablik, unfortunately, no. I did try to debug it with GDB but the code ran fine for all the test cases that I could think of.

Comment: Then try input 1 2 abc abc. The output of your code is 2 but it should be 3

Comment: @ThomasSablik, right, I hadn't tried that input combination. I will check it with the debugger once I go home. Meanwhile, is it clear to you what is the problem with the code?

Comment: No, I didn't find the problem but if it's for a contest you should use a different approach, e.g. my answer. Your code needs O(n²) operations and my approach needs O(n) operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend a different approach. First create a map for each string. Count the number of each character. Sum up all minima.

E.g.:

s1 = "abcaa" => map1 = {'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}, 
s2 = "ababc" => map2 = {'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}

=> 2 + 1 + 1 common characters.

Instead of a map you can use an array since you can convert a char to an int.

Instead of a map you can use a set if you don't want to count duplicates.

s1 = "abcaad" => map1 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}, 
s2 = "ababce" => map2 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'e'}

With [std::set_intersect](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/) you can determine the common characters.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

int main() {
    unsigned int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        unsigned int n;
        std::cin >> n;
        std::string temp;
        std::cin >> temp;
        std::set<char> intersect(temp.begin(), temp.end());
        while (--n) {
            std::cin >> temp;
            std::set<char> tempSet(temp.begin(), temp.end());
            std::set<char> newSet;
            std::set_intersection(tempSet.begin(), tempSet.end(), intersect.begin(), intersect.end(), std::inserter(newSet, newSet.begin()));
            intersect = newSet;
        }
        for (const auto c : intersect) {
            std::cout << c;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I shall try it out. The specifics of the question had duplicates to be considered as a single character so I'll probably check if it is already present in a map for each character.